# F# array initialization with non-consecutive numbers

Tags: arrays, f#, initialization-list

Is there a short notation to initialize F# array with multiples of N, where N > 1? For example N = 2:

```
{|2; 4; 6; 8; 10;|]
```

Maybe, something analogous to the default N = 1 case:

```
[|a..b|]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for that is in the language:

```
let a = [|2..2..10|];
```

The number in the middle is the step between the values. To be even fancier, you can also use sequence expressions for array initialization:

```
let b = [| for i in 1 .. 10 -> i * i |]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Array.init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273.aspx)

```
let arr = Array.init 5 (fun i -> (i + 1) * 2)
```